# Maintainng custom code in the entity context.cs automatically created code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've searched but I guess I'm not exactly sure what to search on for this...

I am writing a data access layer for my application using the entity framework.  I am performing a database first method so the entity data model is auto-generated.

So the model.context.cs file  under the model.edmx contains this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace com.MyCompany.AppPro.DAL 
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class AppProEntities : DbContext
    {
        public AppProEntities()
            : base("name=AppProEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<UserData> UserData { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<UserKey> UserKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to update this code to accept a connection string outside of this class.  But when I update the model this file gets overwritten (which I'm warned about) in the comments.  I can keep putting the code back in each time I update but there has to be a better way...

Is there any way I can add additional code into this file and have it retained on a DB schema update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the same partial class inside the same namespace with your custom code in a separate file, this is the whole point in using a partial class.

Comment: thanks, sometimes you can't see the trees through the forest.

Comment: @DaBlue please consider flagging my reply as an answer instead of an upvote, thanks.